# Why is the time complexity O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
int algorithm(int n) {
    int k = 0;
    while(n>1) {
       n=n/2;  // integer division
       k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Time complexity is `O(log n)`? Why?

Comment: Because this is the number of iterations and the time complexity of the loop body is O(1).

Comment: This follows almost directly from the definition of log, you should probably start there.

Answer (score 4):

If you write `n` as a binary number, say `11011011`, the successive values it takes before the loop exits are

```
11011011
 1101101
  110110
   11011
    1101
     110
      11
       1
```

Therefore, the number of iterations (final value of `k`) equals the initial *number of bits* of `n`. From

```
2^(k-1) ≤ n < 2^k
```

which is the condition to have `k` bits, you draw

```
k-1 ≤ log2(n) < k.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the operations in the loop, division and addition, are O(1). Now, consider the number of iterations for n = 2^m, for some m, and compare this number with log_2(n). Generalising to n, which are not powers of 2 is easy. Denoting by i(n) the number of iterations of the loop for input n, and taking for 2^m < n < 2^(m+1), note that i(n) = i(2^m) (thanks, integer division).

Comment: IMO you don't explain what the OP doesn't understand: how to estimate the number of iterations.

Comment: "consider the number of iterations for n = 2^m, for some m, and compare this number with log_2(n)". Granted, I don't give the answer, but I do tell how to arrive at it. Give a man a fish, and all that.

Comment: Mh, this amounts to the initial question, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

You repeatedly divide *n* by two until you reach 1 or less. Therefore your stop condition is (roughly) expressed by the equation *n/2^k = 1* <=> *n = 2^k* <=> log_2 n = k ( / is an integer division in your code). Roughness is allowed because we are dealing with *O( )* and constants will disappear anyway.